# Speeding through the primes until they look uniform

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Imagine you are traveling out the $x$-axis such that your velocity at $x$ is $v(x)$.
If $v(x)=1$, then you pass the primes at increasingly longer intervals, on average (of course there are close primes, e.g., twin primes).
Is there some function $v(x)$ so that the event of passing a prime becomes uniformly random,
in that the expected time between passing primes becomes a constant?
For example, $v(x) = x / \log^2 x$ doesn't quite work, in that the delay between
passing primes still increases with $x$.

Comment: Does it matter how many primes did we pass with the last move?

Comment: Alex B.'s comments below indicate that essentially what I am asking for would require the resolution of an open problem, open even assuming the Generalized Riemann Hypothesis!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A tautological solutions would be variations of the step function
$$
v(x) = 1/d(p_x)
$$
where for each $x$, $p_x$ is the biggest prime less than or equal to $x$ and $d(p)$ is the distance between the prime $p$ and the next prime. Of course, we can turn this into a smooth function by multiplying by suitable [bump functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function) (and adjusting the levels of the steps slightly, so as to insure that the time it takes to travel between two primes stays the same).

Unfortunately, a non-tautological solution, even conjectural, that insures that the time intervals between two primes on average converge to a constant value is completely out of reach. If we had such a closed form formula for the velocity, then in particular it would yield an approximate formula for the prime counting function $\pi(x)$ whose error term tends to 0. This is not even known under the GRH and might not even exist.

Comment: Perhaps my question is not well-posed.  I am imagining that, as you travel along the $x$-axis, you click a stop-watch as you pass each prime, and note the time difference.  If you travel at a constant velocity, this time difference will grow.  If you maintain a huge acceleration, the primes will occur closer together in time.  I'm seeking a velocity function that makes them show up at regular intervals (on average). What is not well-posed here is that I would want the velocity to satisfy some smoothness criteria to exclude your step function. :-)

Comment: "Or do you want the mean of the deviations to tend to 0?"  Yes! But now I see that I'm inadvertently asking for the solution to an open problem!

Comment: @Joseph Thank you for clarifying the question. I have incorporated all our comments into the answer, so I guess we can delete them.

Answer (score 6):

My closest interpretation to your question is if there is a function $v(t)$ such that

$$\pi\left( \int_0^T v(t)dt\right)\sim aT$$

for some "prime-hitting" frequency $a$. The answer is yes. We'll look at a basic example. Denote the position function as $F(T) = \int_0^T v(t)dt$, then, using PNT ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem) / [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeNumberTheorem.html)), transform the equation into a more tractable form

$$ \frac{F(T)}{\ln F(T)} \sim aT.$$

We will do one better and ensure *equality* of the above expression. (This is not the same as equality in the original asymptotic formula with $\pi(\cdot)$, but still entails our original desired form as a logical consequence.) Take the negative reciprocal of both sides,

$$ \frac{1}{F(T)} \ln \frac{1}{F(T)} = -\frac{1}{aT},$$

and then use the Lambert W function ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) / [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html)) to simplify,

$$ \ln\frac{1}{F(T)} = W\left(-\frac{1}{aT}\right)$$
$$ F(T) = \exp\left( - W\left(-\frac{1}{aT}\right)\right)$$

which gives:

$$ v(t) = \frac{d}{dt} \exp\left( - W\left(-\frac{1}{at}\right)\right).$$

Note you can use a derivative formula for $W(\cdot)$ found in the linked articles alongside the chain rule if you so desire. And you can use even better asymptotes of the prime counting function with the same inverse-function reasoning in order to obtain velocities with more uniform prime-hitting.

EDIT: There might be problems in realizing this empirically due to the domain of the $W$ function and branch cuts. I'm having problems figuring how how to get a working graphic off of Alpha, or if my formula needs to be augmented to address some technicality I'm not seeing.

Comment: This is a nice analysis!  Ultimately I'd like a computable function $v(t)$ so one could (essentially) make a movie of passing the primes, as if they were roadside signs.